# How to Correctly Destroy ToneUnit after Tone Fades Out?

Tags: iphone, synchronization, core-audio, remoteio, audio-converter

I'm generating tones on iPhone using AudioUnits based on Matt Gallagher's [classic example](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html). In order to avoid the chirps and clicks at the beginning/end, I'm [fading the amplitude in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10051806/1431728) in the `RenderTone` callback. I'd like to destroy the ToneUnit at the end of the fade out, that is, after the amplitude reaches zero. The only way I can think to do this is to call an instance method from within the callback:

```
    if (PlayerState == FADING_OUT) {
        amplitude -= stepsize;
        if (amplitude <= 0) {
            amplitude = 0;
            PlayerState = OFF;
            [viewController destroyToneUnit];
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this is more challenging that I had thought. For one thing, I still get the click at the end that the fadeout was supposed to eliminate. For another, I get this log notice:

```
<AURemoteIO::IOThread> Someone is deleting an AudioConverter while it is in use.
```

What does this message mean and why am I getting it?

How *should* I kill the ToneUnit? I suspect that the click occurs because `RenderTone` and `destroyToneUnit` run on different threads. How can I get these synchronized?

---

In case it's helpful, here's my `destroyToneUnit` instance method:

```
- (void) destroyToneUnit {
    AudioOutputUnitStop(toneUnit);
    AudioUnitUninitialize(toneUnit);
    AudioComponentInstanceDispose(toneUnit);
    toneUnit = nil;
}
```

If I NSLog messages right before and right after `AudioUnitUninitialize(toneUnit);`, the notice appears between them.

Answer (score 6):

I also ran into the same issue. When I called the destroyToneUnit from the main thread, the warning went away.

```
[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(destroyToneUnit) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: thanks for you code. I had exactly the same problem. You code solved my problem.